# Can I use the verb 'ride' referring to a journey in a car?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, expressions

If I'm behind the wheel, "I'm driving". But if I am in the back seat or the passenger front seat what am I doing? Am I riding in the car?"

"I rode 20 miles." (My Dad was the driver.)

"We are riding the through the tunnel."

Are the above sentences common and correct?

Comment: The usual way of dealing with this is to use the extended sense of 'drive': 'We were driving through the tunnel' (which covers driver and all passengers).

Comment: You wouldn't say "I drove 20 miles" if you were not the driver. You'd say, "We drove 20 miles". I'd say, "We're going through a tunnel..." if I were a passenger or a driver with passengers, and either "I'm going through a tunnel" or "I'm driving through a tunnel" if I were alone. If you're talking about a public vehicle (like a bus), things might change a bit, I'd have to think about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but you have to be sensitive to the context. Anyone reading your two examples in isolation would not immediately think you were in a car. By contrast, when we hear Chuck Berry sing

> Ridin' along in my automobile
>
> My baby beside me at the wheel

it is clear not only that he is in a car, but that he is also driving it.

Comment: Rather the opposite, surely: it's clear that he is _not_ the one driving the car.

Comment: Given the social context, it seems to me that he would be driving what is, after all, ‘my automobile’. The syntax allows that interpretation if you place _My baby beside me_  between commas. But my point was to show how _ride_ can be used to describe travelling by car.